# Map fields to their own row in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was tasked with migrating data from a MSSQL server to a MySQL server.  I figured it'd be easier for me to first convert the MSSQL database to an MS Access database, so I could mess with it, then export it as MySQL.

So, I have a table, called companies:

```
companyID |    name        |     c_phon  |  c_email                   | c_address
    1       StackOverflow     5555555555     Joel@stackoverflow.com      NYC
    2       Google            5558675309     Google@google.com           NYC
```

In our new database, we've changed how these fields are being saved.  Instead of each row having a phone number, email, and address, we're using a prefs table.

prefs:

```
prefID  |  prefName
  1         c_phone
  2         c_email
  3         c_address
```

My issue is, how to I convert each field into it's own row in our companyPrefs table.  It should look something like this:

```
companyID | prefID | prefValue
    1         1      5555555555
    1         2      Joel@stackoverflow.com
    1         3      NYC
    2         1      5558675309
    2         2      Google@google.com
    2         3      NYC
```

I don't know how to use vbscript or whatever, so I was trying to do this using SQL.

```
INSERT INTO comanyPrefs (companyID, prefID, prefValue)
SELECT companyID, prefID, @fieldName
FROM companies, preferences
WHERE @fieldName = prefName
```

Obviously this doesn't work.  How can I select fields using a variable field name?  How can I insert a row for each field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  However, you would need to insert for each possible field, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO companyPrefs (companyID, prefID, prefValue)
SELECT companyID, (select prefID from prefs where prefName = 'c_phone'), c_phone
FROM companies where c_phone is not null
UNION
SELECT companyID, (select prefID from prefs where prefName = 'c_email'), c_email
FROM companies where c_email is not null
UNION
SELECT companyID, (select prefID from prefs where prefName = 'c_address'), c_address
FROM companies where c_address is not null
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cf87/1

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to manually add each field name to the query.  I was hoping I could do this dynamically.

Comment: Well you could construct the code dynamically from VBA.  For example, build the query in a string, and for each field name, e.g. `strQuery = strQuery & "SELECT companyID ... where prefName = '" & theFieldName & "', " & theFieldName & " FROM companies where " & theFieldName & " is not null"`, for example.  You would also have to  do possible casting if any of your source columns are not textual.

Comment: I don't know how to use VB, I think it would take me longer to do that than just manually entering the field names :-P

Comment: And if you wanted to do it entirely in SQL, you could build the string the same way using a `varchar` variable, concatenating the query, and executing the result with `exec(@sql)`.

Comment: Ya, if you don't have a whole bunch of fields, say 15-20, and this is a one-time process, or the code only has to be written once, might be just as easy to manually key it all out. I'm a fan of cost-value based decision over cleverness :)

Comment: Access is giving me an error.  If I do `SELECT...UNION...SELECT` (without the `INSERT`) it works fine.  But, when I add `INSERT INTO companyPrefs (companyID, prefID, prefValue)`, it says `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression...`.  When I click 'OK', it highlights `UNION`.  What's going on?

Comment: I got it working, I had to do `INSERT INTO companyPrefs (companyID, prefID, prefValue) SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... UNION ... SELECT) q`.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess INSERT...SELECT...UNION might not be supported in MS Access.. One sec.  **Edit**: Great!